# EF Core transaction lifetime

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, transactions, using

We are using our select statement inside transaction scope because of concurrency concerns.
The question is, if I put my transaction in `using` statement, do I still have to call `Commit()` method explicitly to be sure that the transaction is closed or `Dispose()` method will do the job?

Here's example code:

```
await using (var transaction = await Context.BeginTransactionAsync())
            {
                callbackUrl = await this.SomeRepository.GetResultAsync(request);
                await transaction.CommitAsync();
            }
```

Comment: You have to call Commit explicitly. Imagine exception inside using block. Following your thoughts it should commit on Dispose? I think not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions) would be your best friend in such situations.

Once you choose handle transactions manually, you should call `commit` or `rollback` in your program flow.

EFCore's transaction already have an atomic behavior for the `SaveChanges` method: it will commit it's implicit transaction  changes if everything succeed and rollback on any error occurrence.

On a first sight of your code, there is no need to call `commit` (or even use transaction) once you are not making any changes to database, its just a query.  I bet you are using this like a to change the context's query isolation level, is that right?

Maybe you should elaborate a little bit more of your context and the 'concurrency concerns' to get a more effective help.

Comment: You're right. We're using transaction for the isolation level. We need to use our queries in snapshot level. In that case I think no need to commit since transaction will close on dispose.

Comment: @TuralMustafayev, what if you guys just create a separated dbcontext with this isolation level set up and reuse it in every place you need that behavior? seems it would be a cleaner solution, with no transactions.

Answer (score 2):

*using* is only calling a *Dispose()* method at the end. It will not Commit the transaction automatically.

Disposing also rolls back all the changes made within transaction. If you dispose before commit or just dispose it will roll back all the changes and close the transaction.

If there are no changes you don't have to commit the transaction to close it. You can just wait for the using to do it's job and dispose the transaction which will close it anyway.

Generally if you don't expect anything to be commited just don't use commit.

Comment: I know but, is it enough to dispose a transaction, or we still have to call Commit it even we didn't do any DML operation?